# Compile NCFTP for 32 bit target

Tags: linux, cross-compilation, 64bit, 32bit

System details- Linux Kernel Release(2.6.18-164.el5), Machine Hardware Architecture(i686)

I have to compile ncftp client source code on 64 bit architecture to create 32 bit binaries. I don't have admin rights to place 32 bit libraries for compiling it with CFLAG= -m32. How can I do it without any system environment changes.Only by using makefile or toolchain changes to perform cross compilation. Or if there is any ncftp code present to create 32 bit binaries.

Comment: Is there any reason you cannot use the precompiled [EL5 RPM](https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/epel/5/i386/ncftp-3.2.2-1.el5.i386.rpm) that was provided at the time specifically for that OS?  If you have to build from source, I would suggest starting with the [source RPM package](https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/epel/5/SRPMS/ncftp-3.2.2-1.el5.src.rpm).  Using the `mock` project from Fedora you should be able to rebuild the source RPM on a 64-bit machine for the 32-bit architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer you may like to try.

I'm unsure if you had tried it already, since there is no mention of this on your question, if you have please don't mind the suggestion.

Try [download NcFTP](https://www.ncftp.com/download/). It offers a download of precompiled binaries for NCFTP both client and server.

It would be probably easier to have access to a machine you do have admin access however.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

> Linux Kernel Release(2.6.18-164.el5)

"2.6.18 **el5** " : That's »Redhat Enterprise Linux 5« or the free version »Redhat CentOS 5«. The kernel update level : -164 was year 2009. I.e. RHEL 5.4 ... a very old version.

> compile ncftp client source code on 64 bit architecture to create 32
>   bit binaries

NcFTP Client, source-src ftp://ftp.ncftp.com/ncftp/ncftp-3.2.6-src.tar.gz

Not an easy task to setup a modern 64bits OS to compile ncftp for old glibc-2.5 . I guess that a 32bit linker is required too. Please note that "EL5" originally is a year 2007 OS.

The easy way is actually to install the 32bits CentOS 5.11 - i386 on an old computer or into a virtual machine. Then ncftp-3.26 can be built in a minute.

EL5 result : `ncftp-bin-3.26-i686-el5.tar.gz` 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/16a4bvsPr9EsOJR6V2ZKVPIU9P5uFChkN/view?usp=sharing